# Странное поведение компиляторов

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang

Написал пример кода, который очень меня смутил. MSVC компилирует его без проблем в,но Clang и GCC нет.Баг компилятора или реализация?

```
template<typename T,typename...U>
struct A
{
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"primary template"<<std::endl;
    }
};


template<typename T,typename...U>
struct A<T,U...>
{
    static void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"partial template"<<std::endl;
    }
};




int main()
{

    A<float,int>::print(); 


    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Tfense4oK

Comment: Код бы вставили в текст вопроса.

Comment: добавил) Просто там ещё ссылка на годболт была.

Comment: Явно баг MSVC (как обычно).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Тоже показалось это странным) Но не стоит сильно их ругать, они тоже стараются.

Comment: Ничего они не стараются, они его жопой пишут. D:

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ахахха ладно) Пойду кину им репорт, пусть посмотрят.